# Are cantrips in Baldur's Gate 3 unlimited or not?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I thought cantrips could be used an unlimited number of times, but during battle they ran out. My wizard doesn't have any spells to use anymore in long battles and becomes useless.

What's the difference then between cantrips and prepared spells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cantrips do not run out in Baldur's Gate 3.

Keeping in mind the game is still in early access, there are a lot of bugs and glitches still being worked out. If you're saying it run out because it disappeared from the quick bar, you can re-add by dragging it from the party's spells menu (k). If it's on your quick bar but it says you need a spell slot when you click it, then try reloading a save. Either way, I recommend submitting a bug report to Larian.

Comment: ah so its a bug?. Yeah the firebolt and frost thingy cantrip dissappear in the quick bar after several uses during the battle. the other spells tho, the prepared ones stays but cant be used.

Answer (score 9):

With the full version being out we can confirm:

### It depends on the cantrip

You have an unlimited number of uses for *most* cantrips. There are some, however, that are limited to once per short rest, e.g. Mage Hand.

Thanks to @jono in the comments:
"There are several ways to exploit the Mage Hand since it's essentially an endless summon that can Shove and Throw things without making NPCs hostile to you, so I assume that's why they limited it."

Using a cantrip will count as an *action* or *bonus action* (depending on the cantrip), and will be subject to all corresponding rules.

Comment: There's at least one exception: Mage Hand is once per short rest.

Comment: @mmatthews Are you thinking of the githyanki mage hand? That's different from the spell version

Comment: @Pyritie All versions of Mage Hand are limited to one cast per Short Rest, even if they're cantrips. There are several ways to exploit the Mage Hand since it's essentially an endless summon that can Shove and Throw things without making NPCs hostile to you, so I assume that's why they limited it.

Comment: Mage hand is very handy in combat when there are small enough enemies that can be pushed down from tall places :) Excellent for pushing down goblin archers.

Comment: Note that in the *Dungeons & Dragons* 5th edition tabletop RPG rules, [cantrips](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Cantrips) "can be cast at will, without using a spell slot and without being prepared in advance". Certain cantrips like *mage hand* might be limited in this way because you can't have more than one *mage hand* active at once (in the tabletop RPG, recasting the spell causes the previous casting of *mage hand* to go away).